# Numerically Controlled Oscillator (NCO) Sample quantity

Tags: digital-logic, fpga, oscillator, clock

Ive been doing some research on NCOs and some initial information (or lack of information) is bugging me. Ive read a few articles on this topic:

[FPGA based NCO](http://www.edn.com/design/test-and-measurement/4315472/FPGA-based-design-yields-low-cost-arbitrary-frequency-generator)

[Blog on NCOs](http://blog.thelonepole.com/2011/07/numerically-controlled-oscillators/)

But i still don't understand how such an oscillator can vary frequency without reducing the number of samples between different frequencies.

All of the articles on this topic mention the following arrangement:

Increment Word ---> Phase Accumulator (Clocked by the main clock) ----> Sine wave look up table ---> DAC and so on.

[image]

The above arrangement (as far as i can understand) varys the amount by which it iterates through the table thereby varying how long it takes to go through it and produce a complete sine wave. However lets say my Look-up table consists of 2^8 entries and i increment through the table by 1 each time, i will go through all 2^8 samples and get a frequency of Clock/256

Now if i were to instead increment by 4 each time, i would only go through 256/4 samples and would thus get a frequency 4 times the previous example.

So as even though the frequency is varied isn't the number of samples present at the different frequencies also different.

How can the frequency be varied without effecting the number of samples present in the wave?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This technique is generally called [Direct Digital Synthesis (DDS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_digital_synthesizer).

> How can the frequency be varied without effecting the number of samples present in the wave?

It doesn't; The sample rate is fixed. I.e. the synthesizer/oscillator outputs some number of samples per second, this does not vary, the sample value varies.

Lets say you used a sample rate of 8khz, if you looked at the one second of output you will have 8000 samples. The highest frequency that could be output at this rate is 4khz which is the [Nyquist_frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_frequency). For this 4khz the sample value would alternate 0,255,0,255... your table index would 0,128,0,128 or (127,255... or whatever). The index would increase by 128 each sample. A 2khz signal would see an index increasing by 64 each sample. Both signals would have 8000 samples for the whole second, the 2khz signal would have half as many cycles as the 4khz signal in the same time, because it is half the frequency!

Now if you meant cycle instead of wave, then the answer would be that you can't have the same number of samples/cycle for another frequency with the same sample rate. If you need more fidelity (i.e. more samples) you will have to increase the sample rate.

Comment: That answers my question perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

A DDS/NCO is basically a sample rate converter that has a fixed output sample rate and a variable input sample rate.  In your example, setting the input frequency control word to 4 instead of 1 increases the frequency of the output waveform by increasing the sample rate of the input waveform (stored in the table) by a factor of 4 while simultaneously decimating it by 4 (only keeping 1 out of every 4 samples).  Think about it this way: if you play back the table at 4 times Fclk, then you will get 4 times the output frequency.  However, you can only generate output samples at Fclk, so you have to drop 3 samples every 4 (decimate by 4).  This is implemented by skipping over three table entries every clock cycle.

The real power of a DDS is in that you can have a very large phase accumulator with more bits than your lookup table so you can generate frequencies with extremely fine resolution - specifically, the sample frequency divided by the accumulator range.  For a 250 MHz clock and a 32 bit accumulator, the frequency resolution is 0.058 Hz.  The tradeoff is that the samples will not be absolutely perfect due to truncating the phase, but this is generally less of an issue than the number of output bits that the lookup table provides.

Storing a very large lookup table is a slightly difficult problem.  For a 16 bit output, you generally want a table with 2^18 entries.  This does not fit in a FPGA block RAM.  There are techniques to store a compressed version of a lookup table in multiple lookup tables, then perform some sort of interpolation or other reconstruction to get the correct value.  One example is https://github.com/alexforencich/verilog-dsp/blob/master/rtl/sine_dds_lut.v .  This module is a 16 bit LUT for the sine function with an 18 bit input.  Normally it requires 2^18*16 = 4M bits for storage, but this one only uses 16*512*2+8*256 = 18k, a savings of 227x.

Answer (score 1):

Variable sample rate is different then skipping samples,
i was thinking the same way as those replys, and trying to find out the same as the topic starter.

link as proof its different : http://www.electricdruid.net/index.php?page=info.wavetableoscs